# Java - Working with IO - Clarification

Tags: java, file, io, filewriter, printwriter

I am working on a few lessons in Java, and the instructor started introducing how IO working in Java. I just have a couple of question that an experience Java programmer could clarify.

The piece of code below is a program that creates a (notepad) text file in the same file directory I am writing my code. After that, it simply prints basic lines of text to that file.

```
import java.io.FileWriter; //Imports Filewriter class
import java.io.PrintWriter; //Imports PrintWriter class
import java.io.IOException; //Imports IOException

public class Chap17Part2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String fileName = "grades.txt"; //Creating name for file
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName)); //Question 1
        outFile.println(85); //Prints to file
        outFile.println(77); //Prints to file
        outFile.close(); //Ends buffer, and flushes data to file.

    }

}
```

**Question 1:** Due to only brief explanations by the instructor, this line of code is a bit confusing to me. I know that in this line, we are creating the "outFile" object. After that, we are calling the PrintWriter constructor, and inside its parameters, we are calling the constructor for FileWriter. Inside of its constructor, we are calling the name of the file we created as a String. That is the confusing part. I'm not understanding exactly what PrintWriter, and FileWriter are doing. It looks like FileWriter is creating our file, and PrintWriter is giving us the println() method to print the two numbers to the file.  After doing research, I have found that you can pretty much achieve the same purpose with both FileWriter, and PrintWriter. What is the purpose for teaching file processing in this manner, and what exactly are the two classes doing? Thank you for the help in clarifying this for me!

Comment: You might consider... reading the javadoc of the classes. They explain what the classes are for, and what they do.

Comment: True, it seems simple enough, however, I have already taken a look at the documentation. The documentation is still slightly fuzzy to read, but these are the definition from Java: 

**PrintWriter**: Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream.

Question: Is the text-output stream the FileWriter in this example?

**FileWriter**: Convenience class for writing character files. FileWriter is meant for writing streams of characters.

Question: Is the FileWriter the stream, and by writing a character file, does it mean it is just creating the file, or also streaming it?

Comment: A file writer is a character stream, that allows writing characters to a file (as its name indicates). It implements Writer. A PrintWriter prints formatted representations of objects to any writer. And a FileWriter is a Writer.

Comment: Thank you for making that more clear, but I have to ask, what exactly do you mean by "formatted representations of objects?"

Comment: That comes directly from the javadoc of PrintStream. It prints double numbers as decimal numbers, objects with their toString() methods, null values with "null", etc.

Comment: Alright, so let me get everything straight, and tell me if this is correct. Basically, in the questioned line of code, I begin by initializing PrintWriter, and calling its constructor in order to convert my printed code to a text file. Initializing the FileWriter within the PrintWriter parameters fulfilled PrintWriter's requirements of establishing a stream for the PrintWriter to send the formatted code to. Would this be correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say it like that. The code is equivalent to `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName); PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(fw);`. So it first creates a FileWriter, which writes characters to a file, and then creates a PrintWriter which prints its values to the FileWriter.

Comment: Excellent, and very clear! This concludes the questions I have about this. If you would provide a formal answer, I will come back, and check it off as correct to close the question. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is equivalent to

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName); 
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

So it first creates a FileWriter, which writes characters to a file, and then creates a PrintWriter which prints its values to the FileWriter.